# What is the proper way for fetching or ignoring lazy loaded objects using hibernate and spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jackson

I am using spring MVC + hibernate + jackson.
Spring version : 4.3.x
Hibernate version : 4.3.x
I want to create two API- one fetching BeanB objects as well while one not fetching BeanB object. I am using fetchtype.lazy for the same.

I have following beans:

```
@Entity
class BeanA
{

@Id
int id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "BeanB_id")
private BeanB beanB;


//getters and setters
}

@Entity
class BeanB
{

@Id
int i;

//getters and setters
}
```

In my controller I have two methods: (Removing service layer to make question small. In my service layer class, I have @Transactional)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/beanA/{id}" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<BeanA> findDetailedBeanAById(@PathVariable("id") int id ) 
    {
        // to return beanA object with beanB
        BeanA beanA = beanADao.findDetailedBeanAById(id);       
        return new ResponseEntity<BeanA>(beanA, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/beanA/{id}" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<BeanA> findNonDetailedBeanAById(@PathVariable("id") int id ) 
    {
        // to return beanA object without beanB
        BeanA beanA = beanADao.findNonDetailedBeanAById(id);        
        return new ResponseEntity<BeanA>(beanA, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

In My Dao

```
public BeanA findDetailedBeanAById(long id) {


        BeanA beanA = (BeanA) getSession().get(BeanA.class, id);
        Hibernate.initialize(beanA.getBeanB())
        return beanA;
    }

public BeanA findNonDetailedBeanAById(long id) {

    BeanA beanA = (BeanA) getSession().get(BeanA.class, id);        
    return beanA;
}
```

When I am hitting findNonDetailedBeanAById controller method, I am getting error as :

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

When I am hitting findNonDetailedBeanAById controller method, I am getting error as :

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)`
```

What changes are needed to be done?

Answer (score 0):

For the detailed findBy method you can build a custom query and fetching the beanB inside of the query, like `getSession().createQuery("SELECT a FROM beanA a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.beanB WHERE a.id == :id")`

For the lazy findBy method I think you need to add the @Transactional(readonly=true) at the controller level, because you are trying to use the beanA after getting it with the service which was annotated as transactional. I think it tries to fetch the beanB from the database but the hibernate session might already be closed.

I was not able to tryout any of my suggestions because I'm only at phone.

Comment: If I add @transactional, it will fetch details from database.. but that is what I don't need. I want to take advantage of lazy loading

Comment: My understanding is that it will only fetch it out of the database as soon as you access the field beanB in your code, before hibernate will only create a proxy object around it.

Comment: Did you try to add a fetch profile hibernate introduced in 3.5? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-profiles